# How to collect and filter images for image recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, image-recognition

Newbee question here: right now I need a relatively large database of images, say a few thousand, for image recognition training purposes.

I found some good ways to get rough results, like playing with google images search terms e.t.c. and binge-downloading them. But the results (images) are still only like 50% representative of what I would need on the image (other images are either related things, or plain garbage). Picking by hand isn't really an option, because it would take a whole lot of time. So is there a quicker way of picking those images? Like using some other image recognition network, or specific software?

Comment: Why don't you use existing collections such as ima......t? (Fill the gap yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search Kaggle for image recognition competitions such as [cdiscount-image-classification-challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/cdiscount-image-classification-challenge/data).
The data is usually available easily.